# Override a wordpress theme language file using a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, po, mo

I am using a wordpress theme that contains several language files. I would like to modify a language file to "white label" the theme I am using. I will also be making other admin-css changes to the theme, therefore, I'd like to create a plugin that allows me to do all of this.

What I am unsure of how to do is create a custom plugin that would override a themes language file - is this possible?

I have so far tried this:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Layers Whitelabel test
Plugin URI: http://www.skizzar.com
Description: Plugin to whitelabel layers for Skizzar
Author: Skizzar
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.skizzar.com
*/ 

function set_myplugins_languages() {
    load_textdomain( 'layerswp', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/language' );
}
add_action('init', 'set_myplugins_languages');
```

But so far no joy - as in, it doesn't load the new language file in place of the existing one.

Anyone got any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, why do you need a plugin for this?

The theme style.css have similar code to

```
Plugin Name: Layers Whitelabel test
Plugin URI: http://www.skizzar.com
Description: Plugin to whitelabel layers for Skizzar
Author: Skizzar
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.skizzar.com
```

So you can simply change theme display name, url, author etc.

Basically it's easy to do, however it's against theme copyrighting ;) Even if this is a GPL theme you should refer to original developer.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question isn't clear enough. I'm trying to override a language file that is already within the theme. I don't want to edit the theme files as I will loose them when I update. For example, I want to override theme-name/languages/en_US.po with my_plugin/language/en_US.po